# HTML. Set the scrolling bar in a determinated position

Tags: html, scrollbar

I would like to set the position of the scrolling bar in a determinated position. In my case I have in a `<div>` all the hours of the day by hh:00 hh:30 so 48 rows and I would like to set the position in the current time of the day or aprox.

Is there any way to do that?

**Update**

I'm talking about a div element. I forgot to put the escape key.

Comment: Can you describe what kind of element you are talking about?  Is this the whole page, a div or even maybe a combo box?  It is unclear from your question as to what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just put an anchor in at each of the 48 rows and then have a link to that anchor?

**UDPATE**
You could have the following:

```
<a name="133000"/>time: 13:30:00
```

For your row for the time 1:30 pm. The `<a name="133000"/>` is a named anchor.
When you want ot have a link to that part of the page you do this:

```
<a href="thisDocument.html#133000">Go to 13:30:00</a>
```

A better link to what I'm talking about: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_NAME.html

Comment: could you explain me that solution a bit wider? I get the concept of anchor but not the way to do it. Thank you